# Wildfly 10 + Rest Easy web service. Getting Could not find resource for full path error

Tags: java, rest, wildfly-10

My Web.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My Application config class is as follows:

```
@ApplicationPath("/api/catalogManagement/v2")
public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig
```

My Rest service is class is as follows:

```
@Stateless
@Path("/catalog")
public class CatalogFacadeREST extends AbstractFacadeREST<CatalogEntity> {
    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response find(@QueryParam("depth") int depth, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) throws BadUsageException {
}
}
```

I am calling this rest service: http://localhost:8080/DSPRODUCTCATALOG2/rest/api/catalogManagement/v2/catalog?depth=5

But I am getting:

```
21:17:53,739 ERROR [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (default task-1) RESTEASY002010: Failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8080/DSPRODUCTCATALOG2/rest/api/catalogManagement/v2/catalog?depth=5
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.ClassNode.match(ClassNode.java:75)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootClassNode.match(RootClassNode.java:48)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getResourceInvoker(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:445)
```

Comment: I am using jersey classes such as: import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig; in ApplicationConfig Java file. But Wildfly 10 uses Rest Easy by default. Is this causes a problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is of course some problems with your configuration. You don't have to add

```
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

in your web .xml as javax.ws.rs.core.Application is not a servlet at all. Rather you have to configure like this;

```
@ApplicationPath("/<your path>")
public class ApplicationReSTService extends Application {
}
```

Also there is no issue in giving forward slash with your relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the issue:

```
@ApplicationPath("/api/catalogManagement/v2")
```

should be, without the leading slash

```
@ApplicationPath("api/catalogManagement/v2")
```

[source](https://github.com/tmforum/DSPRODUCTCATALOG2/blob/master/src/main/java/org/netbeans/rest/application/config/ApplicationConfig.java)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have overridden 'getClasses' method in your Application class (or Config class). As a result, if those classes are not there, there are not visible for configuration...